# How to start with web service testing using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to learn web service testing using jmeter.Can anyone tell me how to proceed which samplers and request should i use.How should i practice as I am not having any web service to test.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The recommended test element for web service testing is "usual" [HTTP Request sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request).

You can get a minimal web service test plan (it includes a web service endpoint by the way) in a couple of clicks like:

JMeter Main Menu -> File -> Templates -> Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan -> Create

[image: JMeter Web Service]

References:

- [Building a WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html)
- [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)

Comment: Hi Thank you . I could understand it. but can u tell what is Send Soap Action in SOap/XML -RPC Request. I am getting error when i do the same thing in SOap/XML -RPC Request as done with HTTP request

Comment: You need to use [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send [SOAPAction](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html) header

Comment: Thank you so much.